# lm sensors: not showing up cpu fan speed and cpu temp

Tags: 18.04, lm-sensors

chipset I guess ought to be: Nuvoton NCT6793D

```
nct6793-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                       +0.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                       +1.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                       +3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                       +3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                       +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                       +0.15 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                       +0.92 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                       +3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                       +3.09 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                       +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                      +0.92 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                      +0.92 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                      +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                      +1.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                      +0.39 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                      564 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                      549 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                      718 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                        0 RPM
SYSTIN:                    +30.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                    +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                   +30.5°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                   +30.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                   +30.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                   +93.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:              +29.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
                                    (crit = +100.0°C)
PECI Agent 0 Calibration:  +30.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:      +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:              +0.0°C  
intrusion0:               ALARM
intrusion1:               ALARM
beep_enable:              disabled

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +37.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +37.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

2 intake fans and one outtake fans are showing up as it should be.

any thoughts, why cpu temp/fan speed not showing up explicitly?